# Sencha render multi component

Tags: extjs

This is a little bit of a hard problem to explain. If you look below you will see valid JSON.

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('CPC.store.Website.StatisticChartByDate1', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: [
        ...
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'myurl',
        extraParams: {typeCP: Ext.util.Cookies.get('typeCP')},
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data.rows',
            metaProperty: 'data.statistic'
        }
    }
});
```

This is my data response:

```
{
    "data":{
        'statistic': {...}
        'rows' : {...}
    }
}
```

How can I render `rows` for chart and `statistic` for `FieldContainer` below?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a "master" model with 2 `hasMany` associations for rows and statistics. A master record will then exposes a store for each, that you can use in your views/components. In order to read the `hasMany` association from the master data, use the [`associationKey`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association-cfg-associationKey) option of the association.

Here's a short example:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Row', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,fields: ['name']
});

Ext.define('App.model.Statistic', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,fields: ['name']
});

Ext.define('App.model.Master', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'

    // Don't forget requires if models are defined in different files
    ,requires: [
        'App.model.Row'
        ,'App.model.Statistic'
    ]

    ,fields: ['id']

    ,hasMany: [{
        name: 'rows'
        ,model: 'App.model.Row'
        ,associationKey: 'rows' // read association data from this node in the response
    },{
        name: 'statistics'
        ,model: 'App.model.Statistic'
        ,associationKey: 'statistics'
    }]

    ,proxy: {
        type: 'ajax'
        ,url: 'data1.json'
        ,reader: {
            type: 'json'
            ,rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
});

App.model.Master.load(1, { // use id if relevant or anything if the proxy does the job
    success: function(masterRecord) {
        var rowStore = masterRecord.rows(),
            statisticsStore = masterRecord.statistics();

        // Use these stores for your different usages
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: @riso: How can I add  two different sets of data from the same store to be reflected in any two UI elements at the same time? please, help me..!

Comment: The getters generated by HasMany associations (e.g. `myMasterModel.rows()`) return stores based on the associated model. Bind these stores to your component using e.g. `bindStore` for data view or grids.

Comment: @riso: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#Chart')[0].bindStore(chartStore); worked for me but Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#Total')[0].bindStore(statisticStore); not worked :(